# Export Error When Using GraphQL Query Components?

Tags: javascript, meteor, graphql, apollo-client

I'm studying the new (and awesome) GraphQL query components. There seems to be something wrong with my export statement. I'm getting the console error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
>   .....App.js:30:4
>
> .....
>
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>   .....index.js/ index.js:77:4

Here's the code:

**App.js**

```
 1  import React from "react";
 2  import gql from "graphql-tag";
 3  import { graphql, Query } from 'react-apollo';
 4  import { withApollo } from "react-apollo";
 5  import ResolutionForm from "./ResolutionForm";
 6  import GoalForm from "./GoalForm";
 7  import RegisterForm from "./RegisterForm";
 8  import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";
 9  import Goal from "./resolutions/Goal";
10 
11  const RESOLUTIONS_QUERY = gql`
12    query Resolutions {
13      resolutions {
14        _id
15        name
16        completed
17        goals {
18          _id
19          name
20          completed
21        }
22      }
23      user {
24        _id
25      }
26    }
27  `;
28 
29  const App = ({ refetch }) => (
30      <Query
31          query={RESOLUTIONS_QUERY}
32          fetchPolicy={refetch ? 'cache-and-network': 'cache-first'}
33      >
34          {({ loading, data: {resolutions, client, user } }) => {
35              if (loading) return <span>loading....</span>
36              return (
37                  <div>
38                      {user._id ? (
39                          <button
40                              onClick={() => {
41                                  Meteor.logout();
42                                  client.resetStore();
43                              }}
44                          >
45                              Logout
46                          </button>
47                      ) : (
48                          <div>
49                              <RegisterForm client={client}/>
50                              <LoginForm client={client}/>
51                          </div>
52                      )}
53                      <ResolutionForm/>
54                      <ul>
55                          {resolutions.map(resolution => (
56                              <li key={resolution._id}>
57              <span
58                  style={{
59                      textDecoration: resolution.completed ? "line-through" : "none"
60                  }}
61              >
62                {resolution.name}
63              </span>
64                          <ul>
65                              {resolution.goals.map(goal => (
66                                  <Goal goal={goal} key={goal._id}/>
67                              ))}
68                          </ul>
69                          <GoalForm resolutionId={resolution._id}/>
70                      </li>
71                  ))}
72              </ul>
73                  </div>
74              );
75          }}
76      </Query>
77  );
78 
79  export default withApollo(App);
```

In terms of named vs default imports, here's the matching import statement, from `index.js`:

**import.js**

```
14 import App from "../../ui/App";
   .....
70 const ApolloApp = () => (
71     <ApolloProvider client={client}>
72         <App />
73     </ApolloProvider>
74 );
75 
76 Meteor.startup(() => {
77     render(<ApolloApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
78 });
```

How do I correct this error?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Comment: you should post all relevant files and the error should contain at least the line number

Comment: Line numbers have been added per your request. I believe all relevant files have been included.

Comment: This happens when a component is not a React component, string or function. Usually this is because one of them is `undefined`. The easiest way to debug this is to break in the render method and look at the components or alternatively `console.log` all of them (`console.log(Query, RegisterForm, ...)`). PS: I don't think you need the `awaitQuery` wrapping higher order component.

Comment: @Herku That was very helpful! By examining the data at that point, I discovered that my installed version of react-apollo did not include Query. After updating it the code ran without error. If you would like to enter your response as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message appears when a component is not a React component, string or function. Usually this is because one of them is `undefined`. The easiest way to debug this is to break in the render method and look at the components or alternatively `console.log` all of them (`console.log(Query, RegisterForm, ...)`).